# Don't know how to get launcher icons bigger?

Tags: launcher, icons

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 lts on my dell xps 13.
I have a problem with all the symbols, texts, icons.
Everything is to way small to read.
Even the starter icons and the menu.
I have tried to make them bigger in the appearance settings, but they were still way to small.
Does anyone know what should i try to fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In **System Settings → Screen Display**, you can move the **Scale for menu and title bars** slider in the lower left corner to a value greater than 1 to zoom all text and icons by the specified factor.

[image]